# How to exclude my asp.net application from stylecop rules?

Tags: c#, asp.net, coding-style

I have an ASP.net application that has been done long back ago. But now our deployment tool shows **StyleCop** warnings for this application using **styleCop rules** from TFS build.

I is almost more than 2000 warnings (lot of naming conventions issues). The deployment will be possible only after fixing those warnings.

**Can anybody have solution to exclude my application from StyleCop warnings?**

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it, by using below code

E.g.

```
[SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules", "SA1202:ElementsMustBeOrderedByAccess", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
private void SomeMethod()
{
}
```

http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1202.html

Other Rules:
http://www.stylecop.com/docs/StyleCop%20Rules.html

Comment: I have to skip everything in my app from style cop rules. Then where should I put the code?

Comment: http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/Suppressions.html
You can put it on class.
as well as
StyleCop does not support the notion of global suppressions or file-level suppressions. Suppressions must be placed on a code element.

Comment: I have paste the code just above a class, and tried to "Run Style Cop" by right clicking the project including that class. but the warning count remains the same as previous one.

Comment: You need to find out exact rule and find it in rules on stylecop site and put it on method